# How to assign an instance of an object to an array?

Tags: game-maker

**Game Engine**: Gamemaker Studio

I am making a game similar to bejeweled. I decided to use an array to control everything. Placing instances of objects themselves in to the array seems to be the best way to accomplish this because then I won't have to check where the square is in the room, and then compare it to where in the array that lines up, and so on and so forth.

However, I can't figure out how to do that. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While languages such as C and C++ have pointers, Object-Oriented programming language like Java have instance identifiers to reference existing class instances.

Game Maker: Studio provides any existing instance with a built-in variable: [`id`](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/objects%20and%20instances/instances/instance%20properties/id.html). An instance `id` is used to "talk to" a particular instance of an object among the others currently in the room.

I'm assuming that by assigning an instance to an array you mean to save a reference to a given object within an array. As you create your gems - for example in a `while` or `for` statement - you can add a line to the code block to save the id of the new instance:

```
var my_inst;
for (var i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    // Other code of yours //
    my_inst = instance_create(dx,dy,obj_Jewel);
    array_id[i] = my_inst.id;    // OR: array_id[i] = my_inst;
    // Even more code
}
```

Of course, you can expand this code to make it work with 2D arrays if you need to, even with data structures.

You can save an instance `id` by asking for its variable, but remember you get its `id` right when it is created by using the function [`instance_create()`](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/objects%20and%20instances/instances/instance%20functions/instance_create.html), as it is the return value of the function.

Once you get all your `id`s in the array, you can perform all the game logic as you will.

Comment: I cannot stress more the issue of http://gamemaker.info/en/manual/403_05_instances and the quote "Note that the assignment of the instances to the instance id's changes every step so you cannot use values from previous steps.". A far better way to do this is to have an array that the jewel types sit within. It will also be more memory efficient. I don't have a manner of implementing this though, so feel free to take it as a free thought and run with it if it inspires you. Great answer though! If it weren't for that "feature", this would be awesome!